# Undefined reference with Allegro 5 after updating MinGW to 64 (Windows 7, Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, allegro, mingw-w64

I'm having "Undefined Reference" to the whole schmere, and everything is properly setup (As it seems).

All the libs are linked (I mean, ALL of them, so it's impossible that I've missed something):

[image]

The headers are properly included:

[image]

And here's my toolchain executables for the compiler (After the change / update).

[image]

I'm so paranoid by now that my paths do not even have spaces anymore, and it just does not work (It was working with MinGW x86, but it is full of bugs, string conversion does not work, and whatever. It was installed on C:\MinGW, but now it's installed in a completely different path (The new one)). I've changed the path environment variable accordingly.

So, any ideas? Something in the toolchain executables is wrong? (I've never set it up manually before).

Comment: Are you statically or dynamically linking Allegro? Are you sure the Allegro library paths are correct? Is there a way to see in the log exactly what Code::Blocks is running when it runs the compiler?

Comment: Are you trying to link 32-bit static libraries to 64-bit objects? That ain't gonna work. In any case there is nowhere near enough information in this post for anyone to help you.  If you try again, make a simple "Hello world" program that calls 1 allegro function . Say, 10 lines for the whole program. And make sure you show the commandline sent to the linker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem, by returning to the buggy MinGW x86 (Reinstalling the whole Code::Blocks with MinGW by default, and erasing the Code::Blocks .conf file in AppData).

So, I'll have to use the buggy version of GCC because it's the one that "sees" Allegro 5 (For some reason, there's some incompatibility. It just does not find the Allegro functions).